# Executing published geoprocessing service for customized GP tool from Python scripting?

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing-service

I have published the geoprocessing services for a GP tool.

How can I use this link in python scripting to execute the GP tool?

http://VM01-AG01-NJ:6080/arcgis/rest/services/FeatureClassToGeodatabase/GPServer

Comment: This has been documented here http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/sharing-workflows/using-a-service-in-python-scripts.htm

Answer (score 1):

I use the [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module for stuff like this.  There are also built in modules to do this (urllib).  To run a published GP service, you simply need to make a request to the REST endpoint.

I have published a [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/Bolton-and-Menk-GIS/restapi) to do these kinds of tasks.  Here is an example of how to run the Esri drive time analysis GP service with my restapi module (can be found [here](https://github.com/Bolton-and-Menk-GIS/restapi/blob/master/restapi/test/restapi_samples.py)):

```
import restapi, os

# Test Geoprocessing Service
gp_url = 'http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Network/ESRI_DriveTime_US/GPServer/CreateDriveTimePolygons'
gp = restapi.GPTask(gp_url)

# get a list of gp parameters (so we know what to pass in as kwargs)
print '\nGP Task "{}" parameters:\n'.format(gp.name)
for p in gp.parameters:
    print '\t', p.name, p.dataType

point = {"geometryType":"esriGeometryPoint",
         "features":[
             {"geometry":{"x":-10603050.16225853,"y":4715351.1473399615,
                          "spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}}}],
         "sr":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}}

# run task, passing in gp parameters as keyword arguments (**kwargs)
gp_res = gp.run(Input_Location=str(point), Drive_Times = '1 2 3', inSR = 102100)

# returns a GPResult() object, can get at the first result by indexing (usually only one result)
# can test if there are results by __nonzero__()
if gp_res:
    result = gp_res.results[0]

    # this returned a GPFeatureRecordSetLayer as an outputParameter, so we can export this to polygons
    print '\nOutput Result: "{}", data type: {}\n'.format(result.paramName, result.dataType)

    # now export the result value to fc (use the value property of the GPResult object from run())
    drive_times = os.path.join(folder, 'drive_times.shp')
    restapi.exportFeatureSet(drive_times, gp_res.value)
```